# Automate regression by rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `data.frame`

```
set.seed(100)
exp <- data.frame(exp = c(rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 10)), re = c(rep(seq(1, 10, 1), 2)), age1 = seq(10, 29, 1), age2 = seq(30, 49, 1), 
                  h = c(runif(20, 10, 40)), h2 = c(40 + runif(20, 4, 9)))
```

I'd like to make a `lm` for each row in a data set `(h and h2 ~ age1 and age2)`
I do it by `loop`

```
exp$modelh <- 0

for (i in 1:length(exp$exp)){
  age = c(exp$age1[i], exp$age2[i])
  h = c(exp$h[i], exp$h2[i])
  model = lm(age ~ h)
  exp$modelh[i] = coef(model)[1] + 100 * coef(model)[2]

}
```

and it works well but takes some time with very large files. Will be grateful for the faster solution f.ex. `dplyr`

Comment: no it is row-wise, even though the groups exist

Comment: I apologize, are you trying to create a regression with only 1 degree of freedom? I may suggest you reconsider your plan of action...

Comment: @Jason, it is just an example of bigger problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can try with `rowwise()` and `do`.  Inside the `do`, we concatenate (`c`) the 'age1', 'age2' to create 'age', likewise, we can create 'h', apply `lm`, extract the `coef` to create the column 'modelh'.

```
library(dplyr)
exp %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    do({
       age <- c(.$age1, .$age2)
       h <- c(.$h, .$h2)
       model <- lm(age ~ h)
       data.frame(., modelh = coef(model)[1] + 100*coef(model)[2])
    } )
```

gives the output

```
#   exp re age1 age2        h       h2    modelh
#1    A  1   10   30 19.23298 46.67906  68.85506
#2    A  2   11   31 17.73018 47.55402  66.17050
#3    A  3   12   32 26.56967 46.69174  84.98486
#4    A  4   13   33 11.69149 47.74486  61.98766
#5    A  5   14   34 24.05648 46.10051  82.90167
#6    A  6   15   35 24.51312 44.85710  89.21053
#7    A  7   16   36 34.37208 47.85151 113.37492
#8    A  8   17   37 21.10962 48.40977  74.79483
#9    A  9   18   38 26.39676 46.74548  90.34187
#10   A 10   19   39 15.10786 45.38862  75.07002
#11   B  1   20   40 28.74989 46.44153 100.54666
#12   B  2   21   41 36.46497 48.64253 125.34773
#13   B  3   22   42 18.41062 45.74346  81.70062
#14   B  4   23   43 21.95464 48.77079  81.20773
#15   B  5   24   44 32.87653 47.47637 115.95097
#16   B  6   25   45 30.07065 48.44727 101.10688
#17   B  7   26   46 16.13836 44.90204  84.31080
#18   B  8   27   47 20.72575 47.14695  87.00805
#19   B  9   28   48 20.78425 48.94782  84.25406
#20   B 10   29   49 30.70872 44.65144 128.39415
```

---

We could do this with the `devel` version of `data.table` i.e. `v1.9.5`.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`), create a column 'rn' with the option `keep.rownames=TRUE`.  We `melt` the dataset by specifying the `patterns` in the `measure` to convert from 'wide' to 'long' format.  Grouped by 'rn', we do the `lm` and get the `coef`.  This can be assigned as a new column in the original dataset ('exp') while removing the unwanted 'rn' column by assigning (`:=`) it to `NULL`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
modelh <-  melt(setDT(exp, keep.rownames=TRUE), measure=patterns('^age', '^h'),
   value.name=c('age', 'h'))[, {model <- lm(age ~h)
      coef(model)[1] + 100 * coef(model)[2]},rn]$V1

exp[, modelh:= modelh][, rn := NULL]
exp
#    exp re age1 age2        h       h2    modelh
# 1:   A  1   10   30 19.23298 46.67906  68.85506
# 2:   A  2   11   31 17.73018 47.55402  66.17050
# 3:   A  3   12   32 26.56967 46.69174  84.98486
# 4:   A  4   13   33 11.69149 47.74486  61.98766
# 5:   A  5   14   34 24.05648 46.10051  82.90167
# 6:   A  6   15   35 24.51312 44.85710  89.21053
# 7:   A  7   16   36 34.37208 47.85151 113.37492
# 8:   A  8   17   37 21.10962 48.40977  74.79483
# 9:   A  9   18   38 26.39676 46.74548  90.34187
#10:   A 10   19   39 15.10786 45.38862  75.07002
#11:   B  1   20   40 28.74989 46.44153 100.54666
#12:   B  2   21   41 36.46497 48.64253 125.34773
#13:   B  3   22   42 18.41062 45.74346  81.70062
#14:   B  4   23   43 21.95464 48.77079  81.20773
#15:   B  5   24   44 32.87653 47.47637 115.95097
#16:   B  6   25   45 30.07065 48.44727 101.10688
#17:   B  7   26   46 16.13836 44.90204  84.31080
#18:   B  8   27   47 20.72575 47.14695  87.00805
#19:   B  9   28   48 20.78425 48.94782  84.25406
#20:   B 10   29   49 30.70872 44.65144 128.39415
```

Comment: @Mateusz1981 It can be obtained with `apply`, but `for` and `apply` may not have much difference in speed.

Comment: So far, the first solution works prefect. with the 2, there are installation problems

Comment: @Mateusz1981  I am using R 3.2.2 in linux. It works with the installation directions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: I tried to run a benchmark with the data table solution. I'm getting `could not find function "patterns"`. I'm running 1.9.5

Comment: @PierreLafortune  It was updated recently.  Did you install the devel version recently?

Comment: It's been awhile. I'll retry

Comment: @akrun check out the answer. I'd like to know your thoughts. I couldn't get the data table approach to work even after the new download. And it looks like the base functions round answers differently.

Comment: @PierreLafortune  The `dplyr` may be slower.  But, I think the `data.table` approach should be fast enough.  I dont know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: `Error in melt.data.table(setDT(big.exp, keep.rownames = TRUE), measure = patterns("^age",  : 
  Argument 'verbose' should be logical TRUE/FALSE`

Comment: @PierreLafortune  I downloaded the data.table version few days back.  May be should ping Arun if there is any bugs with any recent updates.

Comment: anyways I upvoted yours, both of your approaches are likely the way to go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88205/discussion-between-pierre-lafortune-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2):

Great (double) answer from @akrun.

Just a suggestion for your future analysis as you mentioned "it's an example of a bigger problem". Obviously, if you are really interested in building models rowwise then you'll create more and more columns as your age and h observations increase. If you get N observations you'll have to use 2xN columns for those 2 variables only.

I'd suggest to use a long data format in order to increase your rows instead of your columns.

Something like:

```
 exp[1,]  # how your first row (model building info) looks like

#   exp re age1 age2        h       h2
# 1   A  1   10   30 19.23298 46.67906


reshape(exp[1,],                                  # how your model building info is transformed
        varying = list(c("age1","age2"),
                                 c("h","h2")), 
        v.names = c("age_value","h_value"), 
        direction = "long")

#     exp re time age_value  h_value id
# 1.1   A  1    1        10 19.23298  1
# 1.2   A  1    2        30 46.67906  1
```

Apologies if the "bigger problem" refers to something else and this answer is irrelevant.

Comment: I knew that some reshaping was a way to solve it but did not manage to figure out the right answer, thanks for that

Comment: I'm glad it was useful. Now the modelling is not row-wise but group-wise. Make sure that what was your unique row identifier before, now it is your group identifier. In this example your row identifier was the combination of variables "exp" and "re" {A, 1}, so in the new format your grouping is still {A, 1} but it now corresponds to 2 rows.

Answer (score 2):

With `base R`, the function `sprintf` can help us create formulas. And `lapply` carries out the calculation.

```
strings <- sprintf("c(%f,%f) ~ c(%f,%f)", exp$age1, exp$age2, exp$h, exp$h2)
lst <- lapply(strings, function(x) {model <- lm(as.formula(x));coef(model)[1] + 100 * coef(model)[2]})
exp$modelh <- unlist(lst)
exp
#    exp re age1 age2        h       h2    modelh
# 1    A  1   10   30 19.23298 46.67906  68.85506
# 2    A  2   11   31 17.73018 47.55402  66.17050
# 3    A  3   12   32 26.56967 46.69174  84.98486
# 4    A  4   13   33 11.69149 47.74486  61.98766
# 5    A  5   14   34 24.05648 46.10051  82.90167
# 6    A  6   15   35 24.51312 44.85710  89.21053
# 7    A  7   16   36 34.37208 47.85151 113.37493
# 8    A  8   17   37 21.10962 48.40977  74.79483
# 9    A  9   18   38 26.39676 46.74548  90.34187
# 10   A 10   19   39 15.10786 45.38862  75.07002
# 11   B  1   20   40 28.74989 46.44153 100.54666
# 12   B  2   21   41 36.46497 48.64253 125.34773
# 13   B  3   22   42 18.41062 45.74346  81.70062
# 14   B  4   23   43 21.95464 48.77079  81.20773
# 15   B  5   24   44 32.87653 47.47637 115.95097
# 16   B  6   25   45 30.07065 48.44727 101.10688
# 17   B  7   26   46 16.13836 44.90204  84.31080
# 18   B  8   27   47 20.72575 47.14695  87.00805
# 19   B  9   28   48 20.78425 48.94782  84.25406
# 20   B 10   29   49 30.70872 44.65144 128.39416
```

In the lapply function the expression `as.formula(x)` is what converts the formulas created in the first line into a format usable by the `lm` function.

**Benchmark**

```
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(100)
big.exp <- data.frame(age1=sample(30, 1e4, T),
                      age2=sample(30:50, 1e4, T),
                      h=runif(1e4, 10, 40),
                      h2= 40 + runif(1e4,4,9))

microbenchmark(
  plafort = {strings <- sprintf("c(%f,%f) ~ c(%f,%f)", big.exp$age1, big.exp$age2, big.exp$h, big.exp$h2)
             lst <- lapply(strings, function(x) {model <- lm(as.formula(x));coef(model)[1] + 100 * coef(model)[2]})
             big.exp$modelh <- unlist(lst)},

  akdplyr = {big.exp %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    do({
       age <- c(.$age1, .$age2)
       h <- c(.$h, .$h2)
       model <- lm(age ~ h)
       data.frame(., modelh = coef(model)[1] + 100*coef(model)[2])
    } )}

,times=5)
t: seconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 plafort 13.00605 13.41113 13.92165 13.56927 14.53814 15.08366     5  a 
 akdplyr 26.95064 27.64240 29.40892 27.86258 31.02955 33.55940     5   b
```

*(Note: I downloaded the newest 1.9.5 devel version of data.table today, but continued to receive errors when trying to test it.
The results also differ fractionally (1.93 x 10^-8). Rounding likely accounts for the difference.)*

```
all.equal(pl, ak)
[1] "Attributes: < Component “class”: Lengths (1, 3) differ (string compare on first 1) >"
[2] "Attributes: < Component “class”: 1 string mismatch >"                                
[3] "Component “modelh”: Mean relative difference: 1.933893e-08"
```

**Conclusion**

The `lapply` approach seems to perform well compared to `dplyr` with respect to speed, but it's 5 digit rounding may be an issue. Improvements may be possible. Perhaps using `apply` after converting to matrix to increase speed and efficiency.